# Any Chrome's plugin for context menu modification or how to get rid of "Emoji" item

Tags: google-chrome, context-menu, browser-plugin

The world has gone mad about emojis. I can understand this and safely ignore.

But having "*Emoji*" menu item as a **first** of all items in context menu of Chrome's any kind of edit box is a thing that actually irritates me a little bit. Because I use browser for browsing pages and I use text edits for editing texts not for throwing emojis everywhere.

[image]

Any way I can get rid of it? Any Chrome's extension to modify Chrome's context menus?

Comment: Is it a Windows only issue? Can't seem to find it in Ubuntu Chrome 75. Or has it been since  fixed?

Comment: Probably Windows only. Not only not removed, but now those idiots even added a keyboard shortcut for it (Win+Period). The world would collapse into chaos, if we wouldn't have stupid emojis everywhere?